# Joining entities from a non associated entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have the following 4 classes:

[image of classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr1zd.png)

I'm having problems building a query that results in:

- Game object containing an array of GameParticipant objects
- Each GameParticipant object contains an array of GameEvents

Current code, executed from my GameParticipantRepository:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $query = $queryBuilder
        ->select('p', 'pl', 'e')
        ->leftJoin('p.player', 'pl', 'WITH', 'p.player = pl')
        ->leftJoin('SomeBundle\Entity\GameEvent', 'e', 'WITH', 'pl = e.player')
        ->getQuery();

$players = $query->getResult();
```

The query above returns an array with GameEvent and GameParticipant objects, which is not the result I'm after.

Comment: And what is the result you are after ?

Comment: Im after the following result: an array with all GameParticipants and for each GameParticipant his related GameEvents.

Comment: That the normal behavior. Where should go the GameEvents selected as 'e' if they are not mapped in pl or p ? Doctrine can't hydrate them in p because it don't know where to put them ...

Comment: So merging the objects manually is the only solution here?